# Extract text using Google Vision Api combined with Credit Card Scanner?

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, text-recognition

I am trying to understand how text recognition works in Android, so I decided to create an app that can scan credit card and extract info (card number and expiry date).

I found this open source: https://github.com/faceterteam/PayCards_Android and I hoped that it would work properly.

It turns out that this can capture and extract numbers well IF the numbers aren't printed flat on the card.

Now, I know that the Google Vision Api makes it possible for me to make my phone recognize printed numbers on cards, but not embossed numbers.

So I would love to combine these two. Unfortunately, I don't know how to, yet.

I found out that the Google Vision Api can recognize numbers from bitmap. But the point is, I am not familiar to how cameras work in Android.

My plan is to use the PayCards for Android, and while it continuously tries to detect embossed numbers, frame by frame, use Google Vision on these frames to check if there are printed numbers instead of embossed numbers.

Is there a way to get a bitmap image out of a camera preview for me to use Google Vision on? I just don't know where to put my Google Vision codes.

Help me, please.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer.

Put the codes in the scanner part.

Comment: Hello Andy K. I had the same idea as you. I have the same problem, I don't know where to put the google vision code. Did you manage to evolve in your solution? 
If so could you give me some idea or show some source code. Thanks in advance.